# My React UI is not updating although changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change my react UI according to the change in state, I'm using true and false states, but when I add a change state using an onClick handler, the state changes  because I added a console.log to log the state changes but my UI is not updating, at this point  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is what i tried below

This is my state declaration file, I'm trying to separate my logic from  UI

```
import { useState } from "react";

const datasetViewToggle = () => {

 


    const [datasetViewToggleState, changeDatasetViewToggle] = useState(false);

    return {
        datasetViewToggleState,
        changeDatasetViewToggle
    };
};

export default datasetViewToggle;
```

This is where I implement the onClick Handler

```
return ( < div className = "w-[250px] h-[300px]" onClick = {() => {changeDatasetViewToggle(true);
                console.log(datasetViewToggleState);
            }
        }>
```

This is  the UI screen I need to change according to the State

```
import React from 'react';
import DatasetGrid from './components/DatasetGrid';
import { FaPlus } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import datasetViewToggle from '../hooks/DatasetView';
import DatasetViewScreen from './components/DatasetViewScreen';
import { useState } from "react";




function DatasetScreen() {
  const { datasetViewToggleState, changeDatasetViewToggle } = datasetViewToggle();

  return (

    <>

{datasetViewToggleState == true && (
                <p>
                  View Page
                </p>
            )}

{datasetViewToggleState == false && (
             <DatasetGrid/>
            )}


      
    </>
  )
  

}


export default DatasetScreen
```

Comment: How is your click handler being used in relation to the DatasetGrid component? Custom hooks are not global states. If you import your datasetViewToggle hook into two different components, you will have two hooks with two independent states.

Comment: My click handler is simply changing the state of the hook imported in the dataset grid component to true,I checked and it's working, but as you said, my other screen simply is not seeing the change because custom hooks are not global states, how do I achieve what I'm looking for here? Should I add global state management like redux or is there a simpler solution, thanks

Comment: Yes if the components are totally separate and you can't pass props between them easily, you should consider Redux.

Comment: awesome thanks, let me do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought i might add the answer from comments

How is your click handler being used in relation to the DatasetGrid component? Custom hooks are not global states. If you import your datasetViewToggle hook into two different components, you will have two hooks with two independent states. – adam.k  2 days ago

My click handler is simply changing the state of the hook imported in the dataset grid component to true,I checked and it's working, but as you said, my other screen simply is not seeing the change because custom hooks are not global states, how do I achieve what I'm looking for here? Should I add global state management like redux or is there a simpler solution, thanks – Macphail Magwira yesterday

Yes if the components are totally separate and you can't pass props between them easily, you should consider Redux. – adam.k 22 hours ago